# stem: inconsistent size of x and y

Tags: octave

I have just started with Octave this month and I'm starting to have some problems a I do not understand. I keep getting this error stem: `inconsistent size of x and y`
and I don't know why.

```
octave:17> sig2=([100:2:120])
sig2 =

   100   102   104   106   108   110   112   114   116   118   120

octave:18> stem([10033:10053],sig2,'*')

error: stem: inconsistent size of x and y
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/private/__stem__.m at line 413, column 11
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/private/__stem__.m at line 37, column 50
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/stem.m at line 81, column 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different! 100 to 120 by 2 result in 10 values. 10033 to 10053 by 1 result in 20 values. You might want to change one of them.

```
sig2=([100:2:120]) 
stem([10033:2:10053],sig2,'*')
```

Comment: I had the suspicion that the difference in the number of values was the problem, now I know it. Many thanks buddy

Comment: check it by use size(...)